# Django QuerySet: fetch objects that contain at least one of the elements in set

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two Models, which have many-to-many relationship. How is it possible to fetch each object of one Model (say Model A), which is related to at least one common object of Model B, with a given object of Model A? Like fetching blog posts which share at least one tag object with the given blog post object.

Comment: Is harsh to give an answer without seeing actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Using your blog example:

```
post1 = Posts.objects.get(id=1)

posts_with_same_tags = Posts.objects.filter(tags__in=post1.tag_set)
```

Does that answer your question?

QuerySet API Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

ManyToMany API Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/